# Facing error in generating the chart using the sample test code mentioned in node-export-server git repository

Tags: node.js, highcharts, phantomjs

I am facing issue in generating the charts in my local. I have followed the steps mentioned in the 'https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server' and used npm install for installing post cloning the repo. I have agreed to the license terms and for High Chart version the supplied value is 11.0.0.  Post that I ran the server using the command `node ./bin/cli.js --enableServer 1`.

The request used as input is below:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"infile":{"title": {"text": "Steep Chart"}, "xAxis": {"categories": ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar"]}, "series": [{"data": [29.9, 71.5, 106.4]}]}}' 127.0.0.1:7801 -o mychart.png
```

Server Side the following error is presented:
__  ___       __         __               __
/ / / (*)*__ */ /*  *****/ /*  ____ ******/ /******

/ /*/ / / __ `/ __ \/ ___/ __ \/ __` / __*/ __/ ***/

/ __  / / /*/ / / / / /**/ / / / /*/ / /  / /*(**  )
/*/ /*/*/_*, /*/ /*/_**/*/ /*/_*,*/*/   _*/****/

****//***/                  __     _____

/ ****/  ______  ____  *****/ /*   / ***/***  ______   _____  _____
/ __/ | |/*/ __ / __ / ***/ **/   _* / _ / __*/ | / / _ / ***/
/ /****>  </ /*/ / /*/ / /  / /*    __*/ /  **/ /   | |/ /  **/ /

/*****/*/|*/ .***/_***/*/   _*/   /***_/_**/*/    |***/_**/*/

/*/

```
  [error] work 
  9e5b7d24514a4b7785927e1e23956e55 could not be completed, sending: an error occured when rendering the chart: SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 24432
```

System Details in which this is tried:
Node -v18.17.1
npm -9.6.7
node-export-server-2.1.0
high chart - 11.0.0
OS - Ubuntu 20.04.6
`

Comment: Have you tried using the new Puppeteer based version instead of Phantom? 
https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server#puppeteer-version-information

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: No, Currently we are working on version 2.1.0 @Michal

Comment: I am getting below error on running the sample curl request:

incoming: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ','\n" +
    '\n' +
    '  phantomjs://code/worker.js:658 in loop\n' +
    '  phantomjs://code/worker.js:73 in doDone\n' +
    '  phantomjs://code/worker.js:503\n' +
    '  phantomjs://code/worker.js:182 in pollForImages\n' +

Comment: It seems that this is a bug related to PhantomJS, unfortunately it is no longer developed, which you can read about here: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/15344. Therefore, the new version of Export Server uses Puppeteer and it would be worth trying to use it.